# Key value pair in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get the value from the map below using the key in my loop. But I am not getting the desired result. When i use the same code outside of for loop then everything is working fine by replacing ! with %. Why is it not working in for loop?

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set map=Abc_Log-Abc;XYZ_Log-XYZ

FOR /D /R %errfolderpath% %%K in (*Log*) DO (

SET folderName=%%~nK

CALL SET folderName=%%map:*!folderName!-=%%
echo !folderName!

SET folderName=%folderName:;=&rem.%
echo !folderName!

)
```

Ideally the second echo should print Abc and XYZ where as it is showing `;=`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the split-trick with ;=&rem cant't work this way.

```
set folderName=%folderName:;&rem.% 
call set set folderName=%%folderName:;&rem.%%
```

The first one fails, because it expands before the for-loop starts.
The second line fails, because in a call-expansion, ampersands (pipes and so on) aren't allowed at all.

But this one should do the job

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set map=Abc_Log-abc;XYZ_Log-xyz

FOR %%K in ("Abc_Log" "XYZ_Log") DO (
    echo(
    echo -----

    SET folderName=%%~nK
    echo entry =!folderName!

    SET folderName=!map:*%%~nK-=!
    echo fn    =!folderName!

    for /F "delims=;" %%a in ("!folderName!") do SET folderName=%%a
    echo result=!folderName!
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks alot for you help and immediate response